# Double comparison

Tags: c++, comparison, boolean, comparison-operators

Can I do this in C++?

```
if (4<5<6)
 cout<<"valid"<<endl;
```

i.e a double comparison? Since I know that I can

```
bool a;
a = 1+2<3+4<5>6;//etc
```

Comment: No, don't do that. But compile with `g++ Wall -g` (i.e. with all warnings and debug info) and the compiler will warn you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, but it won't be what you expect. It's parsed as

```
if ( (4<5) < 6 )
```

which yields

```
if ( 1 < 6 )
```

because `4<5` evaluates to `true` which is promoted to `1`, which yields, obviously, true.

You'll need

```
if ( (4<5) && (5<6) )
```

Also, yes, you can do

```
a = 1+2<3+4<5>6;
```

but that as well is parsed as

```
a = ((1+2)<((3+4)<5))>6;
```

which will evaluate to `false` since `(1+2)<((3+4)<5)` yields a boolean, which is always smaller than 6.

Comment: And `4<5` being true could be casted to 1, which is indeed, but accidentally, less than 6.

Comment: also `< ... >` for the parser it's a template signature, so you will get syntax errors too.

Comment: No `<`...`>` is pased as template thing only in certain template context (the C++ parser is incredibly complex and baroque).

Answer (score 4):

It compiles but won't do what you expect -

```
if( 4 < 5 < 2)
```

same as

```
if( (4 < 5) < 2)
```

same as

```
if( (1 < 2) )  //1 obtained from cast to boolean
```

which is of course true, even though I imagine you were expecting something quite different.

Answer (score 2):

It may be clumsy but this will work:

```
int i, j, k;
i = 4; j = 5; k = 6;
if ( (i < j) && (j < k) )
{
    cout << "Valid!" << endl;
}
```