# What's the behaviour of the Comparison operator?

Tags: c++, c, comparison, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961717/double-comparison)

```
int x=-1;
if(0<=x<=9)
        std::cout<< "Without Logical operator";
if (0<=x && x<=9)
    std::cout<< "With Logical operator";
```

I know about 2nd `if` It's working fine. 
What's happening here in the 1st `if` condition . It goes inside 1st `if` besides `x` is `-1`
And why compiler is not giving `error` when using `(0<=x<=9)`

Comment: `if((0<=x)<=9)`->`if(false<=9)`->`if(0<=9)`

Comment: It's just analogous to `(0 * x * 9)`.

Comment: I don't see any reason for the compiler to complain..its a valid syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, boolean values are just plain integers. In boolean context, `0` is false, and all other values are true. In this case,

```
(0 <= x <= 9)   ==
((0 <= x) <= 9) == // the (0 <= x) evaluates to 0, which is false in boolean context
(0 <= 9)        ==
1 (true)
```